# How to know if iOS app hasn't received a touch event for a certain amount of time

Tags: ios, ios7

I have an iOS 7 app that will be used in a kiosk setting. I would like for the app to go back to the beginning if nobody has used it for a certain amount of time (1-2 min). Any idea how I can do that? Seems like there has to be some way to do it since the screen will lock after not being used for a certain amount of time.

Comment: Use an `NSTimer`. Every interaction (button press, gesture etc...) you should call a method you write like `[self resetTimer]` that invalidates the timer and then recreates itself. Once the timer fires, you should perform an unwind segue. Another SO question that deals with something similar for timers:http://stackoverflow.com/q/17868825/558933

Answer (score 4):

Set an `NSTimer` after every interaction, invalidate it when an interaction occurs. When the timer expires perform the reset.

Comment: How can I hook into every interaction though?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to verify your main.m file to use your delegate file:

```
 int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, @"AppDelegate", @"AppDelegate");
```

You can override the send event method in the implementation file

```
- (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
             [super sendEvent:event];

      // Only want to reset the timer on a Began touch or an Ended touch, to reduce the number of timer resets.
          NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches];
          if ([allTouches count] > 0) {
         // allTouches count only ever seems to be 1, so anyObject works here.
         UITouchPhase phase = ((UITouch *)[allTouches anyObject]).phase;
         if (phase == UITouchPhaseBegan || phase == UITouchPhaseEnded)
         [self resetIdleTimer];
          }
     }

- (void)resetIdleTimer {
   if (idleTimer) {
        [idleTimer invalidate];
       [idleTimer release];
     }

        idleTimer = [[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:maxIdleTime target:self  selector:@selector(idleTimerExceeded) userInfo:nil repeats:NO] retain];
}

- (void)idleTimerExceeded 
    {

      NSLog(@"expected time exceeded");

     }
```